# Uniqueness quantification of planes in vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

- Say we have two parallel lines $l_1\parallel l_2$. *Note: We know the equations for these*
- We know one point on each line, $P\in l_1\land Q\in l_2$.

To **find the plane** $\pi$, such that $l_1,l_2\parallel\pi$ (both lines also lie on $\pi$), must know at least one coordinate on the plane, as well as two directional vectors.

- We know two coordinates, $P$ and $Q$. *Of course we could figure out more with our lines*
- We know one directional vector already.

$$\vec{v} = (a,b,c)$$

---

The other vector, according to the *task*, can be determined by looking at an arbitrary point on each line and figure out the directional vector by subtracting $A$ from $B$.

Of course, given the information, it's comfortable to just calculate $\vec{PQ}$, as we already know these points.

Given two directional vectors and a point, it's easy to figure out the affine form of our plane $\pi:a'x+b'y+c'z+d' = 0$.

Simply look up the normal vector for the plane by calculating the vector product:

$$\vec{n}:(a',b',c') = \vec{v} \times \vec{PQ}$$

$d'$ is solved trivially.

Now, what if I took two other arbitrary points, other than $\vec{PQ}$, such as $\vec{AB}$ where $B$ is a point on $l_1$ and $A$ is a point on $l_2$. After trying this out, it led to the same plane $\pi$. Meaning a plane is uniquely quantified by two parallel lines going through a plane.

---

#### The question

When I think about this geometrically, I can't help but to think something is wrong. What stops you from simply *rotating* the plane around the normal vector? The plane would still go through two lines, yet would, I'm assuming, yield a different equation for the plane.

The two drawn planes below look different to me.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plane extends infinitely in all directions it encompasses. Rotating the plane about a normal vector therefore does not change the plane.

Comment: Ah. I *think* I get it now. I wouldn't perceive any change in perspective if they extended infinitely. I don't know, it just feels a bit *strange* to me at the moment.